# Run a Firebase Realtime Database query multiple times using for loop in android not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am trying to run a **Firebase Realtime database query** in for loop its not working. also not able to view data in **RecyclerView**.  kindly help me fix this issue. thanks in advance.

```
privte void mLoadData()
{

    for(User user:nameArraylist)
            {
                DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                Query query = databaseReference.child("AllUsers").child(user.getId()).limitToLast(1);
                query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren())
                        {
                            try {
                                USerPojo userPojo = new USerPojo ();
                                
                                userPojo.setType(ds.child("type").getValue().toString());
                                
    
                                userArrayList.add(userPojo);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
    
                        }
                    }
    
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
    
                    }
    
    
                });
    
            }

 
                sAdapterNew = new AdapterNew(getActivity(), userArrayList);
                groupRecyclerView.setAdapter(sAdapterNew );
                sAdapterNew .notifyDataSetChanged();
   
}
```

Comment: "its not working" is really hard to help with. What happens when you run this code in a debugger, and step through it line by line? If you set a breakpoint in `onDataChange`, does it reach that? Does it loop over the data then in the way you expect?

Comment: before completing the for loop execution, adapter is called.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen nameArraylist i am retrieving from another firebase table using one more addValueEventListener.

Comment: Please post your database structure for `/users/someUserId` and your `USerPojo` class..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In firebase ,all callback methods are Async method.That's why adapter gets called before try block.So if recycler view needs data from onDataChange() to populates it's view,we need to move adapter code within onDataChange().

```
        privte void mLoadData(List<user> nameArraylist)
        {
         int i;
         for(i=0;i<nameArraylist.size();i++)
            
                    {
                        DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                        Query query = databaseReference.child("AllUsers").child(nameArraylist.get(i).getId()).limitToLast(1);
                        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                                for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren())
                                {
                                    try {
                                        USerPojo userPojo = new USerPojo ();
                                        
                                        userPojo.setType(ds.child("type").getValue().toString());
                                        
            
                                        userArrayList.add(userPojo);

    //when you run outer for() loop to get data,every time adapter will set new value to recycler view  till loop reach last value.
   //so to avoid that i added if() condition,so that adapter will set all value at once.
     


           if(i==nameArraylist.size()-1) {
                                   sAdapterNew = new AdapterNew(getActivity(), userArrayList);
                                   groupRecyclerView.setAdapter(sAdapterNew );
                                   sAdapterNew .notifyDataSetChanged();
        
                                   }
        
                                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                
                                    }
                                }
                
                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                
                                }
                
                
                            });
                
                        }
            
             
                        
               
            }
```

Comment: Still stuck? @kumar

Answer (score 2):

There are many possible problems with your code, which is why I left a comment that should help you to debug.

But one certain problem is that you're not calling `sAdapterNew .notifyDataSetChanged()` after adding items to `userArrayList`. The UI will not be updated unless you call `notifyDataSetChanged`, so you'll want to call that in `onDataChange` too.

Something like:

```
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()) {
        try {
            USerPojo userPojo = new USerPojo();
            userPojo.setType(ds.child("type").getValue().toString());
            userArrayList.add(userPojo);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        sAdapterNew.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: how to solve the for loop issue query is not running with particular ID,